# Unable to resize filesystem on multipath device

Tags: filesystems, oracle-linux, resize2fs, multipath-storage

I've encountered an issue with multipath storage. I've resized a LUN and have rescanned the system to account for it. Multipath recognizes the new size.

Before rescan:

```
mpathax (36000d310007140000000000000000312) dm-2 COMPELNT,Compellent Vol 
size=50G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw 
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active 
|- 0:0:0:2 sdd 8:48 active ready running 
|- 1:0:0:2 sdbj 67:208 active ready running 
|- 0:0:2:2 sdag 66:0 active ready running 
`- 1:0:2:2 sdcm 69:160 active ready running
```

After rescan:

```
mpathax (36000d310007140000000000000000312) dm-2 COMPELNT,Compellent Vol 
size=200G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw 
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active 
|- 0:0:0:2 sdd 8:48 active ready running 
|- 1:0:0:2 sdbj 67:208 active ready running 
|- 0:0:2:2 sdag 66:0 active ready running 
`- 1:0:2:2 sdcm 69:160 active ready running
```

Attempting to resize the filesystem (`ext4`) fails:

```
[user@server ~] $ resize2fs /dev/mapper/mpathax
resize2fs 1.43-WIP (20-Jun-2013) 
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/mapper/mpathax 
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

This hasn't been an issue on other servers and the filesystem is in active use so I know it isn't corrupted. FWIW, resizes of other, actively used filesystems did not encounter issues.

I've looked around and the only other references to this issue appear to deal with LVM. This is not LVM.

Any thoughts on what I should be looking into?

Comment: Is it `ext3` or `ext4`?

Comment: SO and kernel version?... have you resize the partition first?

Comment: `ext4`. Oracle UEL running `3.8.13-118.4.2.el6uek.x86_64`. Same as the other servers which I was able to complete this task on. There is no resizing of the partition. It's a multipath-based LUN and was resized when I ran `multipathd resize map <mpath>` with the results in the post showing that the size went from 50G to 200G.

Comment: Is `/dev/mapper/mpathax` actually the device that is mounted currently? Also, with Oracle UEL you may need to use `resize4fs` instead of `resize2fs`!

Comment: `resize2fs` has already been used and has worked. The device is mounted but that has not been an issue in the past. Online resize is supported and has performed properly on other servers.